# Filter by ID using PokeAPI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a Region filter for my Pokedex app (first project using React), and I have an idea of what to do but can't make it work. The PokeAPI doesn't have an endpoint that returns data by Region/Generation, but when you fetch all Pokemon data they are already ordered by generation, so my approach is to replace the limit/offset of the data with the "startId" and "endId" of the Pokemon depending on the chosen Region (eg. if "Johto" is selected, startId = 152 and endId = 251). The thing is I can't figure out how to actually put it in place and make it work together with my Type filter (which fetches the data from a Type endpoint) and keep the pagination working too.

Also, if there's a better approach for this, please let me know! This is what I came up with but doesn't mean it's the best way.

This is the fetch const:

```js
    const fetchPokemon = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            var data = null;
            var promises = null;
            var selectType = selectedType.toLowerCase();
            if (selectType === "all") {
                data = await getPokemon(24, 24 * page);
                promises = data.results.map(async (pokemon) => {
                    return await getPokemonData(pokemon.url);
                });
                const results = await Promise.all(promises);
                setPokemon(results);
                setLoading(false);
                setTotal(Math.ceil(data.count / 25));
                setNotFound(false);
            } else {
                const { length, data } = await searchPokemonByType(
                    selectType,
                    24,
                    24 * page
                );
                promises = data.map(async (pokemon) => {
                    return await getPokemonData(pokemon.pokemon.url);
                });
                const results = await Promise.all(promises);
                setPokemon(results);
                setLoading(false);
                setTotal(Math.ceil(length / 25));
                setNotFound(false);
            }
        } catch (err) {}
    };
```

I don't know if I should post any other part of the code, please let me know if I should.

Here's the CodeSandbox link with the whole app: https://codesandbox.io/s/wasivispokedex-kyule7

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind how to make it work is: fetch all pokemons at ones.. store it into pokemon state. then create pagination on pokemon state.

you can write your region as object

```
const regions = {
    all: { name: "all", startId: 1, endId: 898 },
    kanto: { name: "kanto", startId: 1, endId: 151 },
    johto: { name: "johto", startId: 152, endId: 251 },
    hoenn: { name: "hoenn", startId: 252, endId: 386 },
    sinnoh: { name: "sinnoh", startId: 387, endId: 493 },
    unova: { name: "unova", startId: 494, endId: 649 },
    kalos: { name: "kalos", startId: 650, endId: 721 },
    alola: { name: "alola", startId: 722, endId: 809 },
    galar: { name: "galar", startId: 810, endId: 898 }
  };
```

So then you can fetch the start and end id with: `regions['johto'].startId` (for exmaple)

also add `filtered pokemons` state - on change region (or any change) you can use `filter` to filter the result you want to display.

```
setFilteredPokemons(() => {
      pokemon.filter((pokemon) => {
        return (
          pokemon.id > regions[e.target.value].startId &&
          pokemon.id < regions[e.target.value].endId
        );
      });
    });
```

at the end you want to check if the filtered pokemons length > 0, if so you want to display the filtered one. if not you want to display pokemon state (from the original fetch). you can apply the pagination on both of them.

In my opinion its better in this case to fetch all the data from the server and manipulate it on the front end than calling fetch on every change... (less walks to the server/api and easier life to manipulate the data)

I hope something from here helped.

I wanted to create a working example in codesandbox, but i will need to refector alot of your code. therefore i wanted to share my opinion and suggestions. so you can figure out yourself. maybe with less changes..

If you find it helpful and If you need extra information about this aproach please let me know. i will try my best to help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand how to implement it..., but I'll try! Thank you for your answer

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to make it work... :(